# Tooltip in SelectItem in jsf

Tags: java, html, jsf

I am using `t:selectItem` inside a `s:selectOneMenu`. My itemLabel are too long to be seen inside the `selectOneMenu` window. Does anyone know, how to get a tooltip for each selectItem? Appreciate any ideas in this direction.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634563/tooltip-for-each-selectonemenu-items-in-jsf

Comment: sorry pradeep it won't work...

Comment: could you please show the code of your `selectOneMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javascript` for this. Since you haven't provided any code sample I use following sample. You may catch the concept and apply it for your requirement accordingly.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="myCombo">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Label1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Label2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Label3"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

your `javascript` code should be as below.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
         var options = document.getElementById("myForm:myCombo").options;
         for(var i = 0; i &lt; options.length; i++) {
             options[i].title = options[i].innerHTML;
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man..but it also not working...any other suggestion please???

Comment: <script>
          (function() {
            var selectBoxId = '#{myClass.id}';
            var selectName ='myForm:myDataTable:'+selectBoxId+':MySelectItemInSelectOneMenu';
            var options = document.getElementsByName(selectName)[0]
                 .getElementsByTagName("option");
            var index = 0;
            <ui:repeat value="#{MyClass.myItems}" var="_opt">
             options[index++].title = '#{_opt.label}';
            </ui:repeat>
          }());
         </script>